# How to grab values for pickerView from NSDictionary from JSONValue?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, uipickerview

In my code I am using JSONValue to grab an NSDictionary.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{
   {ID = 0, NAME = "Patrick"},
   {ID = 1, NAME = "Ted"},
   {ID = 2, NAME = "John"},
   {ID = 3, NAME = "Allen"},
   {ID = 4, NAME = "David"}
}
```

I would like to return the name of the corresponding ID in the following delegate function:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with JSON.  You have an NSArray containing 5 NSDictionaries.  You only confuse yourself if you think of it as "JSON" at this stage.

Comment: An array in JSON is indicated with brackets: [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // Assuming that you have just one component
    return [jsonDict[row] objectForKey: @(row) ];
}
```

Comment: What does @(row) mean? I know @"string" is the only way to address a string in objective-C, but row is just an NSInteger

Comment: It means `[NSNumber numberWithInt: row];`

Comment: isn't the jsonDict[x] a dictionary itself?

Comment: It's unclear, I don't understand this syntax, in JSON an array is indicated with [], a dictionary with {}, you have posted a dictionary with no keys. So maybe it's an array, I edited the answer.